# How to activate tristate in Buildroot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, buildroot, kconfig

I need to activate tristate support in Buildroot to further expand the functionality, but I'm new and I can't figure out how to activate this feature, as well as why even if I write my simple KConfig with only 1 tristate option, when running kconfig-mconfig I can still only select y/n

Comment: What do you mean by tristate support? Buildroot is the Linux distribution that has a compile-time preconfigure packages. You can't have "module" there.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect wording of the question, I need to figure out how to activate tristate when writing Kconfig configurations, because, as I understand it, this type is disabled by default

Comment: Still, you missed to answer to the question "**why** do you need this?"

Comment: I need to add to Buildroot the ability to build an arbitrary component as a separate package

Comment: @0andriy I don't know about Buildroot, but in PTXdist, tristate items configured as `m` are enabled by default unless deselected by an optional "collectionconfig" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to add

```
config BR2_MODULES
    bool "Modules support"
    option modules
```

to a file `Config.in` after that, tristate is safely displayed in `make menuconfig`

Comment: Wow, TIL. Never thought about this capability.